# Cocoa Bindings: Enable a button if multiple textfields have values

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, cocoa-bindings

I have 5 buttons and 5 text fields. I'd like to set up bindings so that button 1 is enabled only if textfields 2-5 have values..... button 2 is enabled only if textfield 1 & 3-5 have values, etc.

I'm just starting to learn about cocoa bindings. I was hoping I could use them to manage the enabling/disabling of the buttons. When I tried to set up an Enable binding on one of the buttons, it won't let me reference the textfields.

Is this possible (and right) to do with bindings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bindings are not conditional, or at least rather opaque in this respect. You will have to do this in code. Check your text fields text change callbacks and enable the buttons accordingly. Should be just a few lines of code.

Comment: There is an `enabled` binding, and there is a value transformer you can use to bind to whether a property is or is not `nil`.

Comment: True, but this is a rather convoluted approach. In a handler, the logic would result in much more readable code, don't you think?

Comment: It would result in more code. The enabled binding stacks: You can bind enabled to one property, enabled2 to another property, etc., all in IB. As documented in the Cocoa Bindings Reference, the final value of the enabled property is the `AND` of all of the bound-to values.

Comment: @PeterHosey, when I try to set up bindings to the textfields though the Bindings Inspector complains that it can't reference them. I am trying to bind them to File's Owner.self.textfieldA (for example) and File's Owner is my WindowController and it has a property named textfieldA. Any idea why Xcode won't let me reference it when binding?

Comment: @KennyWyland: Nope. Simplest way around that is to create an object controller, bind its content to the FO, and bind the fields to the object controller's `content.textFieldA`.

Answer (score 3):

You won't be able to reference the textfields directly in the bindings for the bitton.

A way to work around this is to create a NSObject subclass - call it ButtonController - and have instance vars for the 5 textfields:

```
@inteface ButtonController : NSObject
{
    NSString *text1;
    NSString *text2;
    NSString *text3;
    ...
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *text1;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *text2;
...
```

In the xib file, instantiate an object for the ButtonController.  Now u can bind things to the button controller instance.

Next, bind all the textfields to the corresponding NSString properties.

Then u can bind the enabled property of the button to ButtonController's properties. When u bind the enabled property of button1, bind it to text2 and check the box for valuetransformer and select "NSIsNotNil".  Once u do that, a second enabled2 binding becomes available and u can bind it to text3 etc.

I think this will work but havent tried it yet.

Comment: You can omit the explicit ivars if you're building for 64-bit only, as you can synthesize them (along with the accessors) in the implementation.